# Passing and Reading Parameters in PM2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I want to pass command line arguments to my script.
In forever I used to pass arguments like

```
forever start example.js 8080
```

I am unable to figure out how to do it in PM2.
I tried

```
pm2 start KratosReq.js  -- -p 8080
```

but while reading from process.argv, the array contains

```
[ 'node', '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js' ]
```

Comment: It worked now.Before I was stopping and starting the program,so it was taking the old parameter structure which was wrong. I deleted the program from pm2 list and then started with it correct parameter structure and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Pm2 wrap  your init script and fork node processes(cluster mode) , i think that is why you have that output , looking for declare [enviroment variables in pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/83) , you can use a json file to start up your server , or you can just start passing --node-args argument(checking pm2 help , there is that argument) , something like :

```
pm2 start KratosReq.js  --node-args="-p=8080"
```

Hope this could help.